# Which is better practice, checking object exists in Manager or Method?

Tags: python, django

In Django/Python what is better practice, checking if object exists outside a `Model Manager` or on the `Method` that calls it? For example,

Manager:

```
class CustomerReferralManager(models.Manager):
    def get_referral(self, mobile_number, campaign):
        try:
            return self.objects.filter(mobile=mobile_number).get()
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            pass
```

Method:

```
referral = CustomerReferral.objects.get_referral(mobile_number=mobile, campaign=campaign)
            if referral:
                referral.complete_referral()
```

**Or this...**

Manager:

```
class CustomerReferralManager(models.Manager):
    def get_referral(self, mobile_number, campaign):
        return self.objects.filter(mobile=mobile_number).get()
```

Method:

```
try:
   referral = CustomerReferral.objects.get_referral(mobile_number=mobile, campaign=campaign)
   referral.complete_referral()
except self.DoesNotExist:
     pass
```

Comment: check out .exists() also.

Comment: @PaulCollingwood but I need the object so I can update ``complete_referral`` ``.exists() `` only returns a boolean, right?

Comment: this is true, but I find the having many try/except blocks for this specific thing can result in less readable code (I'll just go get the object if it exists and hope it's cached anyway). I know try/except is pythonic but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `first()` instead of `get()` so no exceptions will be thrown:

Manager:

```
class CustomerReferralManager(models.Manager):    
    def get_referral(self, mobile_number, campaign):
        return self.objects.filter(mobile=mobile_number).first()
```

Method:

```
referral = CustomerReferral.objects.get_referral(mobile_number=mobile, campaign=campaign)
if referral:
    referral.complete_referral()
```

Comment: Nice. So I guess ``first()`` is the same as doing  ``self.objects.filter(mobile=mobile_number)[1]``

Comment: No, not the same.  Your example will throw `IndexError` in case if filter is empty (did you mean [0]? :-). `first()` in this case will return `None`.  See documantation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#first

Comment: @OrbiterFleet Note that `first` will silently return the first matching object based on the ordering (or otherwise ordered by `'pk'`) if multiple matches exist, while `get()` will raise `MultipleObjectsReturned`. I can't tell if `CustomerReferall`s are uniquely identified by their phone number, but if not, you'll have to think about the desired behaviour.

Comment: @catavaran Mobile is unique so this will work perfectly! Thank you for taking the time to explain. O... and I keep forgetting that index starts from 0! Thanks.